# GDB and trouble with core dumps

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump

Meet my

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostmachine 4.1.2-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 15 08:30:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to learn how to use GDB for debugging C programs.  I think it would be particularly excellent if I could use GDB to ferret out bugs that lead to segfaults.  I have a small program that I've written as a solution to K&R's exercise 1-13, and given an input string of a certain size it will generate a segfault:

```
$ ~/learning_c/KR_exercises/chapter_1/1.13.x`
```

--I provide a string from stdin, and...--

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_dump#Using_systemd), "Systemd's default behavior is to generate core dumps for all processes in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/`."

Okie doke:

```
$ls /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.1\x2e13\x2ex.1000.0da6be3a2b4647c8befe14e0e73af848.1719.1438627150000000.lz4
```

But when I run:

```
$ gdb -q ~/learning_c/KR_exercises/chapter_1/1.13.x /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.1\\x2e13\\x2ex.1000.0da6be3a2b4647c8befe14e0e73af848.1719.1438627150000000.lz4
```

I get:

```
Reading symbols from /home/dean/learning_c/KR_exercises/chapter_1/1.13.x...done.
"/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.1\x2e13\x2ex.1000.0da6be3a2b4647c8befe14e0e73af848.1719.1438627150000000.lz4" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
```

Trying to generate a core dump by attaching GDB to the process [as detailed here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_dump#Making_a_core_dump) only makes my terminal emulator start capturing control characters (`^D`, `^C`, and `^Z` won't work in emulator after attaching GDB), and if a segfault is occuring after attaching GDB it isn't being reported in the shell.

Help me to understand, oh merciful and beneficent lords of Stack Overflow!

**ADDENDUM:**

I've solved this particular issue, thanks largely to WhozCraig, whom suggested that GDB was behaving as it should have when being force-fed an lz4 compressed corefile.  If Craig would be so kind as to post a solution saying something similar, I'd be happy to give him that big 'ol check mark.

The easist solution is to start gdb via a subroutine named `coredumpctl` along with the crashed program's PID, a la

`$coredumpctl gdb *PID HERE*`

This vexes me, Arch, and I may migrate over to Gentoo because of it.

Comment: Not having my linux box handy, I can only speculate that gdb is puking on being fed a LZ4 compressed file as what it *thinks* is a raw core dump? Just a guess, mind you, but perhaps worth a peek.

Comment: This is a perfectly plausible solution!  And now I'm rather embarrassed that I didn't recognize the .lz4 file extension.  As soon as I get done reading the relavent documentation on lz4 and manage to get the core file decompressed, I will report back!

Comment: Have you tried setting break points and stepping through the program with GDB?

Comment: @Rdesmond, I could.  And, for small programs like the one I'm working with, that approach is probably just as effective (maybe faster) than examining the core dump.  My goal here, though, is to learn *how* to use core dumps.  Suppose that a future hypothetical program is huge, or runs for a _really_ long time before segfault, or behavior relies on a bunch of random environmental inputs?  Being able to work with core files makes debugging in those scenarios a little less intractably tedious.

Comment: looking at this page http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html seems that by default if the core size is greater they are compressed.All you need to do is set the Compress value to false

Comment: @Pradheep, This is an interesting approach to a persistent solution.  However, I think I'll decline for two reasons: First, my skills as a system admin rank quaint at best.  Even if I could enumerate all of the effects that altering a journal daemon's config file _might_ have, I doubt I could understand how those changes would behave at a system level. Second, I think that compress value is switched on as a stop-gap measure to keep my journals at a manageable size for as long as possible.  While I hate doing so, I think I'll continue to decompress the corefile through the wrapper.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've solved this particular issue, thanks largely to WhozCraig, whom suggested that GDB was behaving as it should have when being force-fed an LZ4 compressed corefile. <strike>If Craig would be so kind as to post a solution saying something similar, I'd be happy to give him that big 'ol check mark</strike> I'm taking all the credit, though. Bwahahaha!

The easiest [solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_dump#Examining_a_core_dump) is to start gdb via a subroutine named coredumpctl along with the crashed program's PID, a la

$coredumpctl gdb *PID HERE*

This vexes me, Arch, and I may migrate over to Gentoo <strike>because of it</strike>.

Comment: Easiest is just `coredumpctl gdb -1` to debug the latest dump.

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to open a compressed file as if it's a coredump.  Arch isn't to blame, systemd is, and you for not knowing what changed with coredumps.  change /proc/kernel/core_pattern back to "core" if you want the old behavior, or just use coredumpctl gdb

Comment: You can also get the core-dump itself (and then load it wherever you want) with: `coredumpctl dump -1 > core` (to write it to the file `core`)

Answer (score 8):

I have same purpose with you. Just uncompress lz4 file by `lz4` command, then you can debug by `gdb crashed_C_executable_file uncompressed_coredump_file`

Comment: If you use coredumpctl gdb, you don't need to uncompress or recompress it.

Comment: "/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.python.0.5fe0d2b21e0942918513074e7a3a307a.32113.1671175637000000.lz4" is not a core dump: File format not recognized